# Power with integer exponents in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Here is my definition of power for integer exponents following this [mailing-list post](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2015-September/msg00076.html):

```
definition 
 "ipow x n = (if n < 0 then (1 / x) ^ n else x ^ n)" 

notation ipow (infixr "^⇩i" 80)
```

1. Is there a better way to define it?
2. Is there an existing theory in Isabelle that already includes it so that I can reuse its results?

**Context**

I am dealing with complex exponentials, for instance consider this theorem:

[image]

after I proved it I realized I need to work with integers n not just naturals and this involves using powers to take out the n from the exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think something like this exists in the library. However, you have a typo in your definition. I believe you want something like

```
definition 
 "ipow x n = (if n < 0 then (1 / x) ^ nat (-n) else x ^ nat n)"
```

Apart from that, it is fine. You could write `inverse x ^ nat (-n)`, but it should make little difference in practice. I would suggest the name `int_power` since the corresponding operation with natural exponents is called `power`.

Personally, I would avoid introducting a new constant like this because in order to actually use it productively, you also need an extensive collection of theorems around it. This means quite a bit of (tedious) work. Do you *really* need to talk about integers here? I find that one can often get around it in practice (in particular, note that the exponentials in question are periodic anyway).

It *may* be useful to introduce such a power operator nevertheless; all I'm saying is you should be aware of the trade-off.

Side note: An often overlooked function in Isabelle that is useful when talking about exponentials like this is `cis` (as in ‘cosine + i · sine‘). `cis x` is equivalent to ‘exp(ix)’ where `x` is real.